# Using explode on a variable that doesn't have quotes

Tags: php, explode

I have a line that grabs data from a web database, outputting this:

KJFK 180451Z 23007KT 10SM CLR 27/22 A3008 RMK AO2 SLP184 T02670222 403500261

(note, this string changes per hour on a dynamic basis).

That string up there has more information that I want displayed in the end. Let's say I want to display just the `23007KT`.

I was thinking of doing `$elements = explode(" ", $metar);`

Note: `$metar` was previously defined as the action that gets that long string. 
`<td><?php $a = $ad[icao]; $metar = get_metar(strtoupper($a)); ?> </td>`

I think the issue is that I need to add quotes to the beginning of the long string. I have tried putting one of these strings, with the quotes, and it works, but that will only be useful for an hour (because it will change after that time)

I have also tried doing `$elements = explode(" ", "$metar");` but no success.

How do I go about adding in the quotes to the beginning of that string?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($elements);` after `$elements = explode(" ", $metar);`?

Comment: You don't need quotes around `$metar`. Can you show `var_dump($metar);` output.

Answer (score 0):

After using the `$elements = explode(" ", $metar);` you will get an array in the `$elements` variable.

You need to check that it comes correct or not to do that use this code `print_r($elements);`

And as you told that you need **23007KT** from string that will 3rd element.
so use the below code

```
echo $elements['2'];
```

and you will get this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it works for me,

```
$metar='KJFK 180451Z 23007KT 10SM CLR 27/22 A3008 RMK AO2 SLP184 T02670222 403500261';
$elements = explode(" ", $metar);
//print_r($elements);
echo $elements[2];//outputs 23007KT
```